# HP pavilion dv5 doesn't start with AC adapter

Tags: battery, hp-pavilion, charger

I'm experiencing a problem with my HP Pavilion DV5 laptop.  It will not power on with the charger only.  It did so before.  It powers on with the battery, but the charger light on the side next to the cable is flashing, and the light that shows that it is on charge is dead.

I tried removing both the cable and battery, holding down power button for 1 minute, then plugging back only the cable, but it won't start.  It just starts for half a second, giving some power to the lights and then dead.  With only the battery, it starts normally.

The battery hasn't been charging normally for a long time and needed replacement. But, I had it both on cable and battery and it worked with the cable.

I have been running it 5 years on Vista and I recently changed to Windows 7.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that after 5 years your charger is out of warranty, so you will need to buy a new charger. Make sure to buy it from a place that allows refunds, because it *may* potentially be a problem with the power system within the laptop, or the connector that accepts the charge cable. But, most likely, the fault is with the power adapter (charger). Make sure you buy one that is specifically designed by HP to be compatible with your system; don't buy a custom or after-market one, as they are often apt to damage your system from being poorly designed.

Comment: Im not sure yet,because the light at the connector of the cable works.I will test it with a multitester to check if it has the correct outputs..I hope it wont be a bigger problem than the charger.Thank you for your answer

Comment: If you get the new charger and it doesn't help, then worst case you can get a refund, assuming you buy from a vendor that is willing to issue refund. You can also go to most PC tech support shops and they will have known working chargers laying around and would be willing to let you try it out for free (most shops are reasonable like that).